# Where is Eclipse Marketplace in Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I just started with Android SDK and want to install some plugins but i can't find the eclipse market place in android sdk.
Is this part of android sdk already or must it be installed?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

the marketplace could be manually installed:

help->install new software->choose Juno->general purpose  software-> Marketplace client

Answer (score 27):

Try this...

1. Go to Help,
2. Then click Install New Software,
3. Press Add,
4. Name = "your option" and **Location** = "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" then press **OK**,
5. Select all press **Next**,
6. Select **general purpose software**
7. Select **Marketplace client** from the extracted checklist items then press next.
8. Accept all the terms and conditions then press install.
9. Then restart the ADT.

Comment: Step 6: Select **general purpose software** -> Marketplace client

Answer (score 5):

To install Marketplace on android `adt`

Can you follow this path :-

**Help** -> **install new software** -> **choose Juno** -> **general purpose software** -> **Marketplace client**

Answer (score 1):

There is no plugins for android sdk - you can download different versions and tools through SDK Manager.

Eclipse marketplace is for eclipse plugins.
Marketplace is avaliable from "Eclipse Helios".

If you tell us what exactly you want to do - it will be simplier to answer.

Comment: i want to install eclipse plugins like this one: http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/ ("You can install the Android Connector for Maven via the Eclipse Marketplace. Select Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... and search for "android m2e".") or "Checkstyle" and the easiest and best way was always the eclipse marketplace

Comment: Eclipse marketplace and android sdk are two different things. In your case you have to have eclipse helios (or later) and in Help menu you'll find marketplace. You even can not have android sdk at all to use this marketplace and install your plugin.

Comment: And in your case if you visit the link you've provided - "You will need Eclipse Indigo or Juno installed." - in this eclipses there is marketplace in "Help" menu - upadte you eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For adt that use kepler [image].
Help->Install New Software...->choose --All Avaliable Sites--

type marketplace.

refer: [how to install Marketplace client on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676346/how-to-install-marketplace-client-on-eclipse)