# how to install Marketplace client on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I need to install eclipse market place. I'm using Eclipse version which is shipped with ADT Bundle for Android development. I don't know if it is Kepler, Juno or something else.
It's mentioned in the link below to go to Help → Install new Software → Switch to the Kepler Repository → General Purpose Tools → Marketplace Client
But there is no "Switch to the Kepler Repository" there.
[How do I install Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285623/how-do-i-install-eclipse-marketplace-in-eclipse-classic)
I've also tried on installing from this link: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/kepler/
But error says unable to read repository.
What to do?

Comment: What do you have listed in the drop-down 'Work with' in the 'Available Software' dialog shown by `Install New Software`?

Comment: @greg-449 many things including "all available sites" or "android developer tools" or "only local sites" and all my previus links

Comment: Is there one like 'xxxx - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/xxx'? xxx is probably Juno, this is the one to choose.

Comment: @greg-449 yes there is, but the same error happens, Unable to read repository!

Comment: Maybe try 'Preferences / Install/Update / Available Software Sites' and use the `Reload` button to refresh the caches.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply select `All sites` and search for `"marketplace"` on the *Install new software...* wizard.

Comment: I hope, eclipse will be stable some day with all features installed by default.

Comment: I guess that never happens. Using it because of SAP last 5 years and it is still in beta stage, maybee alpha :-/